# Select specific fields in Eloquent eager loading not working

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have a `Notifications` model that belongs to a `User`. I want to load the user when a collection of notifications is selected and only load the model with `names` and `emails`. However, when using the select method, the query returns null.

```
$notifications->load(['user' => function($query){
    $query->select(["name","email"]);
}]);
```

If the parameter for `select()` method is given as below, it gives all the fields:

```
$notifications->load(['user' => function($query){
    $query->select(["*"]    
}]);
```

Comment: Just a question: why would you select when eager loading? If you want to filter results for the response you can add  `protected $hidden = []` to your model.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using $notifications instead of Notification model?

Comment: if you have a collection already created you can't cast ->load on that collection, atleast load method doesn't appear on collection avaiable methods of laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-collections#available-methods

Comment: @GaimZz This is not true: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading

Comment: mmm I see thanks :D

Comment: Eager loading only works if you select the foreign key column (`id`).

Comment: @GaimZz the notification model is injected through the service container. BTW does it make any difference in eager loading?

Comment: @GaimZz Eager loading does works but the select part is the main issue here.

Comment: @BirendraGurung, if my answer isn't working you can try doing your select like this-> $query->select(["id","name","email"]), because as the laravel docs state, when using this you must always select id whether you want or not

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, adding primary key to the parameter was the solution. All I did was added the primary key column (in my case: ID) and that worked in my case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just needed to add the primary key column and that worked fine.

```
$notifications->load(['user' => function($query){
    $query->select(["ID","name","email"]);
}]);
```

This way any constraints can be added to the query.

Comment: If you have it the other way around you need to include the foreign key: `$user->load(['notifications' => function($q){ $q->select(['user_id', 'message']); }]);` because 'id' won't work.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe selecting the fields like this works out:

```
$notifications->load('user:id,name,email');
```

What you are trying is designed to add constraints, not to select some fields

Comment: it won't work with closures when you need to add some constraints to your query.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the foreign_key if you fetch data with select.
Have a look

```
public function index()
{ 
    $employee = Employee::with(['pay_salary' => function($query){
       $query->select(['employee_id','salary_amount'])
             ->whereMonth('paying_date',\Carbon\Carbon::now()->month);
    },'getSalary:id,employeeID,salary'])->get();
    
    return View::make('admin.salary.index',['data' => $employee]);
}
```