# How to select columns of a model together with those of it's relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Controller

```
$articles = Article::with('tags')->latest()->get();
```

Blade

```
@foreach($articles as $article)
    <h2>{{ $article->title }}</h2>
    
    @foreach($article->tags as $tag)
        <span>{{ $tag->name }}</span>
    @endforeach
    
    <hr>
@endforeach
```

The above works. Now, I'd like to select just some columns from the models.

I have tried the following but now the names of the tags are not displayed and not getting any error.

```
 $articles = Article::select(['title', 'created_at', 'body', 'slug'])->with(['tags' => function ($query) {
      $query->select('name');
    }])->latest()->get();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eager Loading - Load only specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994253/laravel-eager-loading-load-only-specific-columns)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048919/laravel-nested-eager-loading-and-select or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50623064/select-specific-fields-in-eloquent-eager-loading-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's eager loading system supports loading only some columns.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns

```
$articles = Article::select(['id', 'title', 'created_at', 'body', 'slug'])
    ->with('tags:id,name')
    ->latest()
    ->get();
```

(You'll typically want to ensure you include `id`, or things get a little wonky.)

Comment: Getting a blank page after trying it!

Comment: Blank pages mean an error of some kind. Check your logs. (And make sure you added your `latest()->get()` to this.)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. Still doesn't show the tags only.

 `$articles = Article::select(['title', 'created_at', 'body', 'slug'])
->with('tags:id,name')>latest()>get();`

Comment: The following query get's executed 

`SELECT "tags"."id",
  "tags"."name",
  "article_tag"."article_id" AS "pivot_article_id",
  "article_tag"."tag_id" AS "pivot_tag_id"
FROM "tags"
 INNER JOIN "article_tag" ON "tags"."id" = "article_tag"."tag_id"
`WHERE "article_tag"."article_id" in (0)`

Comment: You probably want to add `'id'` to your `Article::select` call, in that case. Without it you get the `in (0)` because it doesn't have the article IDs.

Comment: Adding the `id` fixes the issues, thanks a lot. It's all good now.

Comment: You know this is a duplicate...